# Copy new files only in batch

Tags: batch-file

I have looked over the copy and xcopy batch commands. Both of them do not seem to support "copy new files only regardless file date time - name comparing only" option. Please advise.

Comment: To whom it may concern:
[code]
FOR /D %%I IN (%OBTEMP%\Dir*) DO (
FOR %%J in (%%I\Bin\*.DLL) DO (
IF NOT EXIST %INSTALLDIR%\bin\%%~nJ.DLL (
COPY %%J %INSTALLDIR%\bin
)
)
)
[/code]

Comment: How can I format a batch code in the "add comment" text?

Comment: Use the single back tick, on most keyboards the key to the left of 1/! thus `This is code`.  It's inline, so formatting is harder.  You could just answer your own question, which will give you all the formatting possibilities.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have a look at [ROBOCOPY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robocopy). Invoking it with the following switches will recursively copy the files from `source_dir` that do not yet exist in `destination_dir`:

```
robocopy source_dir destination_dir /s /xc /xn /xo
```

Als see the [RoboCopy Manual](http://www.stevelu.com/TechnicalArticles/DevTools/1206.aspx) for an explanation of the switches.

Answer (score 1):

```
/D

 /D:m-d-y     Copies files changed on or after the specified date.
              If no date is given, copies only those files whose
              source time is newer than the destination time.
```

**Edit:** What do you mean by *new*?

Comment: sorry, what I wanted was name comparing option

Comment: @markattwood: So you only want to copy the files if they do not exist in the target?

Comment: Exactly. I have been trying FOR loop. But it's painful. It's simple but why MS doesn't support it.

Comment: Yeah, that DOES sound tricky. I dont have an answer. Good luck  :)

Comment: @markattwood: Basically all you want is a 'never overwrite' option.  :(

Comment: It's not that easy. If I specified /Y option, the CMD would override all files. I'm stuck with a simple copy solution. It takes me 6 lines long with FOR commands for this simple scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should look at [rsync](http://www.samba.org/rsync/). It has a Win32 port and it can copy files based on a number of considerations including whether it exists or is different at the destination.

I think you want the switch:

```
--ignore-existing       skip updating files that exist on receiver
```