# Find and move psedo duplicate files based on portions of filename

Tags: windows, file, batch-file

I have a directorty full of files being exported from a database.
Files get created daily with a version appended to the end of the filename.

Filename syntax:  DocumentNumber_DocumentName_Version.pdf

Goal: Use Windows Batch File to move old versions of new files to /old folder.  Exsisting files that do not have new versions in last 24hrs would be ignored.

DocumentNumber can be variable length, can contain dashes, ends with underscore
DocumentName: can be variable length and include dashes, spaces and/or underscores and can change over time
Version is always at the end, it begins with underscore. Is alpha numeric, alpha always increments.

Ex1: Files of different versions: Directory has....

```
D00003456_BTW-FW001_OPTB_A12.pdf
D00003456_BTW-FW001_OPTB_B9.pdf
D00003456_BTW-FW001_OPTB_C6.pdf
D00003456_BTW-FW001_OPTB_D2.pdf (new)

DocumentNumber is D00003456
DocumentName is BTW-FW001_OPTB
Version is either A12, B9, C6 or D2

** Would like to move all to old folder except D2
```

Ex2:  DocumentName can change from version to version: Directory has...

```
DPP-456_BTW-FW001_OPTB_A1.pdf
DPP-456_BTW-FW001_OPTB_C45.pdf
DPP-456_NEW WIDGET_F6.pdf
DPP-456_NEWER WIDGET_Blue_W2.pdf (new)

DocumentNumber is DPP-456
DocumentName is BTW-FW001_OPTB, "NEW WIDGET" or "NEWER WIDGET_Blue"
Version is either A1, C45, F6 or W2

** Would like to move all to old folder except W2
```

Ex3: only move old versions keep newest version of all files: Directory has...

```
SD0001_I001_A1.pdf
SD0001_ClassyWidget_C45.pdf (new)
SD0034_WIDGET_F6.pdf
00000056_NEWER WIDGET_Gray_W2.pdf

DocumentNumber is SD0001, SD0034 and 00000056
DocumentName is I001, ClassyWidget, "WIDGET" or "NEWER WIDGET_Gray"
Version is either A1, C45, F6 or W2

** Would like to move SD001 all to old folder except C45, others (SD0034 and 00000056) would be ignored
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Copy new files only in batch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3499507/copy-new-files-only-in-batch)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After read this topic several times, I concluded that all versions of same document are identified because they all have *the same Document Number* (you should state this point instead of show us multiple examples and let us to guess it).

The Batch file below solve your problem.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set prevName=
for %%a in (*.pdf) do (
   if not defined prevName (
      rem Initialize process with first name and DocumentNumber
      set prevName=%%a
      for /F "delims=_" %%b in ("%%a") do set prevNumber=%%b
   ) else (
      rem Check if next name have the same DocumentNumber
      set nextName=%%a
      for /F "delims=_" %%b in ("%%a") do set nextNumber=%%b
      if "!prevNumber!" equ "!nextNumber!" (
         rem Yes: Two versions of same file, move the older one
         ECHO move "!prevName!" "C:\dest\dir"
      ) else (
         rem No: Different files, update DocumentNumber
         set prevNumber=!nextNumber!
      )
      rem Anyway, previous name was processed
      set prevname=!nextName!
   )
)
```

Files on disk:

```
00000056_NEWER WIDGET_Gray_W2.pdf
D00003456_BTW-FW001_OPTB_A12.pdf
D00003456_BTW-FW001_OPTB_B9.pdf
D00003456_BTW-FW001_OPTB_C6.pdf
D00003456_BTW-FW001_OPTB_D2.pdf
DPP-456_BTW-FW001_OPTB_A1.pdf
DPP-456_BTW-FW001_OPTB_C45.pdf
DPP-456_NEW WIDGET_F6.pdf
DPP-456_NEWER WIDGET_Blue_W2.pdf
SD0001_ClassyWidget_C45.pdf
SD0001_I001_A1.pdf
SD0034_WIDGET_F6.pdf
```

Result of program:

```
move "D00003456_BTW-FW001_OPTB_A12.pdf" "C:\dest\dir"
move "D00003456_BTW-FW001_OPTB_B9.pdf" "C:\dest\dir"
move "D00003456_BTW-FW001_OPTB_C6.pdf" "C:\dest\dir"
move "DPP-456_BTW-FW001_OPTB_A1.pdf" "C:\dest\dir"
move "DPP-456_BTW-FW001_OPTB_C45.pdf" "C:\dest\dir"
move "DPP-456_NEW WIDGET_F6.pdf" "C:\dest\dir"
move "SD0001_ClassyWidget_C45.pdf" "C:\dest\dir"
```

***EDIT**: Answer to new comments*

As I said before, your explanations are not clear, so I based my solution in your examples. My previous code correctly works with your original examples except in one case: Document Number SD0001 in Ex3. However, in this case you listed files I001 and ClassyWidget *in reversed order!*. Both DIR and FOR commands list ClassyWidget first followed by I001. Why did you reversed they? When I read the problem description I focus on how to solve it, not to check if the data given by the OP is right or wrong! This way, my solution give as older version the last listed file (as shown in all examples).

This new "detail" leads to an entirely different solution, because it now requires two passes through all files to first identify the last version of each DocNumber. Although in the problem description you said that "DocumentName can include underscores", all examples shown include *just one* underscore. The new solution below correctly get the older version when DocumentName have just one or no underscores; if it may have *several* underscores, a "small" modification is needed.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
rem First pass: get oldest version of each DocNumber
for %%a in (*.pdf) do (
   rem docNumber=First token (%%b), version=fourth (%%e) or third (%%d) token
   for /F "tokens=1-4 delims=_" %%b in ("%%~Na") do (
      set version=%%e
      if not defined version set version=%%d
      if "!version!" gtr "!oldestVersion[%%b]!" set oldestVersion[%%b]=!version!
   )
)
rem Second pass: move all versions of each DocNumber, except the oldest one
for %%a in (*.pdf) do (
   for /F "tokens=1-4 delims=_" %%b in ("%%~Na") do (
      set version=%%e
      if not defined version set version=%%d
      if "!version!" neq "!oldestVersion[%%b]!" ECHO move "%%a" "C:\dest\dir"
   )
)
```

Files on disk:

```
00000056_NEWER WIDGET_Gray_W2.pdf
BI0000018307_MW531-ABZ2-Bond-Resc_xls_D2.pdf
BI0000018307_MW531-Triton-Bond-Res_xls_B9.pdf
BI0000018307_MW531-Triton-Bond-Res_xls_C5.pdf
D00003456_BTW-FW001_OPTB_A12.pdf
D00003456_BTW-FW001_OPTB_B9.pdf
D00003456_BTW-FW001_OPTB_C6.pdf
D00003456_BTW-FW001_OPTB_D2.pdf
DPP-456_BTW-FW001_OPTB_A1.pdf
DPP-456_BTW-FW001_OPTB_C45.pdf
DPP-456_NEW WIDGET_F6.pdf
DPP-456_NEWER WIDGET_Blue_W2.pdf
SD0001_ClassyWidget_C45.pdf
SD0001_I001_A1.pdf
SD0034_WIDGET_F6.pdf
```

Result of program:

```
move "BI0000018307_MW531-Triton-Bond-Res_xls_B9.pdf" "C:\dest\dir"
move "BI0000018307_MW531-Triton-Bond-Res_xls_C5.pdf" "C:\dest\dir"
move "D00003456_BTW-FW001_OPTB_A12.pdf" "C:\dest\dir"
move "D00003456_BTW-FW001_OPTB_B9.pdf" "C:\dest\dir"
move "D00003456_BTW-FW001_OPTB_C6.pdf" "C:\dest\dir"
move "DPP-456_BTW-FW001_OPTB_A1.pdf" "C:\dest\dir"
move "DPP-456_BTW-FW001_OPTB_C45.pdf" "C:\dest\dir"
move "DPP-456_NEW WIDGET_F6.pdf" "C:\dest\dir"
move "SD0001_I001_A1.pdf" "C:\dest\dir"
```

**EDIT**: Third solution to *same* problem...

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Filename syntax: DocumentNumber_DocumentName_Version.pdf
rem May be spaces and underscores in DocumentName
rem Goal: Find last Version of same DocumentNumber and keep it (DocumentName don't cares)
rem       Move the rest to other folder

rem First pass: Create *ordered* FILE array with this format: FILE[docNumber,Version.pdf]=docName
for %%a in (*.pdf) do (
   set "fileName=%%a"
   rem Change spaces by slashes in DocumentName
   set fileName=!fileName: =/!
   rem DocumentNumber=first token, Version=last token; separated by underscores
   set docNumber=
   for %%b in (!fileName:_^= !) do (
      if not defined docNumber (
         set docNumber=%%b
      ) else (
         set Version=%%b
      )
   )   
   rem Eliminate DocumentNumber and Version from filename (get DocumentName)
   set fileName=!fileName:*_=!
   for %%v in (!Version!) do set docName=!filename:_%%v=!
   rem Create the array element, restoring spaces in DocumentName
   set FILE[!docNumber!,!Version!]=!docName:/= !
)

rem Delete REM part in two next commands if you want to review the created FILE array
REM SET FILE[
REM ECHO/

rem Second pass: Move all array elements of same DocumentNumber, except the last one
set docNumber=/
for /F "tokens=2-4 delims=[,]=" %%a in ('set FILE[') do (
   rem %%a=docNumber, %%b=Version.pdf, %%c=docName
   if "!docNumber!" equ "%%a" (
      ECHO move "!docNumber!_!docName!_!Version!" "C:\dest\dir"
   )
   set docNumber=%%a
   set docName=%%c
   set Version=%%b
)
```

Comment: Sorry for being unclear in my orginal request, you assumed right. The document number is always constant. I ran your batch code thru some trials and found an issue. How does it determin which file is "older". Is it by date? By sort? what?

Comment: Determination of which file is "older" must be from the alpha character of the "version" at end of filename, because the document name can change over time.

Comment: Try these filenames to simulate my issue: BI0000018307_MW531-ABZ2-Bond-Resc_xls_D2.pdf, BI0000018307_MW531-Triton-Bond-Res_xls_B9.pdf, BI0000018307_MW531-Triton-Bond-Res_xls_C5.pdf.  This should keep the verison "D2"

Comment: Aacini, thanks for your imput!  The document name may contain multiple underscores.  Sorry that my examples did not include this.  So i guess my solution needs the "small" modification. There is no way to identify the last segment of the filename starting at the end?

Comment: Aacini, any futher suggestions?  I am very interested in the "small" modification you suggested.  Is it possible to find the last delim, not knowing how many underscores are in the filename?

Comment: I was playing around with the "set last" for a string and this seemed to work for a simple example, i cannot get it working for a underscore deliminated string.  Am i heading down the correct path?

Comment: @crashwell: See my third solution, this is the last one! ;-(

Comment: @crashwell: May I ask you to pick my answer as both Accepted and Useful one?